# Twilio Lookup API for filtering out phone numbers

Tags: twilio, sms, twilio-api

I have an application that allows users to send SMS to numbers they upload in their account. I am starting to implement the [Twilio Lookup API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/lookup/api) so that we avoid sending SMS to numbers that cannot receive them. It's easy to run a carrier lookup and filter out landlines based on the returned `type` information, but I wanted to know if there was anything else I could glean from the returned lookup information that would indicate a number that doesn't accept SMS.

- Does a blank `mobile_network_code` signify anything?
- Is there any way to tell if a VoIP number cannot receive SMS?
- Does `type = null` tell me anything useful about the phone number?
- Are there any specific `error_code` values that signify the number cannot receive SMS?

Usually the Twilio documentation is pretty thorough but I feel like it's lacking on these pieces of information. Thanks for any information, all you Twilio evangelists!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The Lookup API can very much depend on the underlying sources of data that we can access.

My best answers to your questions are:

> Does a blank `mobile_network_code` signify anything?

That the underlying data could not provide a mobile network code. If the phone number still presents as a mobile number in the type, then you should still be able to send it an SMS. There is, for example, an issue with [carrier data for Canadian numbers](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004563433-Twilio-Lookups-API-is-Not-Returning-Carrier-Data-for-Canadian-Phone-Numbers) that prevents us from providing this data.

- Is there any way to tell if a VoIP number cannot receive SMS?

No, best thing in this case is to try to send the message and catch and log any errors.

- Does type = null tell me anything useful about the phone number?

Not really, again you should try sending messages and handle errors. See the note on [Canadian carrier data](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004563433-Twilio-Lookups-API-is-Not-Returning-Carrier-Data-for-Canadian-Phone-Numbers) for more.

- Are there any specific error_code values that signify the number cannot receive SMS?

There are a number of [error codes that relate to Lookup queries in the 6xxxx range](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors#6-anchor). [60600](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/60600) and [60610](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/60610) mean similar things, that the phone is unprovisioned or out of coverage and that you likely can't send it a message. [60612](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/60612) means it's not a mobile number, but should only be returned for lookup providers that require the number being looked up to be a mobile, which doesn't apply for the `type` information. Other `error_code`s tend to be about your account's ability to use a provider or package for looking numbers up. You can peruse the [catalogue of errors for more information](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors#6-anchor).

Comment: I wasn't aware of those other error codes, and will incorporate those into our code. Thanks, @philnash!

Comment: No problem! It may be a long list, but the [Twilio error directory](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors) is a really useful resource!